# Android Dialog cropping problem on Android 12 devices

Tags: java, android, modal-dialog

We have a number of Apps on the market that use DialogFragment (the AppCompatDialogFragment version). We are finding that on certain devices, Samsung TAB S7 for one, dialogs are truncated so that information and action buttons at the bottom are not displayed. Nothing I have tried will resolve this issue in a way that is consistent across all devices. I have produces a simple layout and code to demonstrate. This code when inserted in to the live app displays as per the truncated image, in a newly created test app it displays normally on the same device! All theming, manifest settings appear similar. I have spent many days on this so any suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
package com.example.dialogclipping;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDialogFragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment;

public class DlgTest extends AppCompatDialogFragment {



    static DlgTest newInstance() {

        return new DlgTest();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.DialogStyle);

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        int targetWidth = 1000;
        int targetHeight = 0;

        // check if specific size setting is required
        if (targetWidth != 0 || targetHeight != 0) {

            var dialog = getDialog();
            if (dialog == null) return;
            var window = dialog.getWindow();
            if (window == null) return;

            var lp = window.getAttributes();
            // overwrite dimensions as appropriate
            if (targetWidth > 0) lp.width = targetWidth;
            if (targetHeight > 0) lp.height = targetHeight;
            window.setAttributes(lp);
        }

    }



    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dlg_test_layout, container, false);
        return view;
    }
    int index = 2;

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        view.setBackgroundColor(0xFF92580C);
        final var closeButton = view.findViewById(R.id.yesButton);
        closeButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            /*
            var message = "Height is " + view.getHeight() + "; bottom view at " + bottomField.getBottom();
            legend.setText(message);
            var afterField = view.findViewById(fields[index]);
            afterField.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            index = (index + 1) % fields.length;

             */
            //dismiss();
        });
    }
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/SettingsDialog"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        style="@style/DialogText.Heading"
        android:minEms="16"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:text="Header line"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:background="@color/blue"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/middleView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@color/black">

    </View>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ButtonBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="right">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/yesButton"
            style="@style/DialogButton.Large"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="Close"
            android:visibility="visible"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/bottomView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="@color/blue">

    </View>
</LinearLayout>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.dialogclipping">

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="false"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:resizeableActivity="false"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    </style>


    <style name="DialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    </style>
```

[image: Real app image]

[image: Test app image]

Comment: Share your same codes... Others can't help you

Comment: I am endeavouring to build a sample app to demonstrate the issue but, as one might expect all works OK in this sample!

Comment: Share your dialog layout and if your setting some params in your dialog fragment share those codes... Might be others can identify... Otherwise how can give idea... It's a generic details

Comment: I have amended the question and added a bit of information.

Comment: Is it Java or Kotlin? You shared mingled source.

and You haven't added your style.

Comment: Is it full screen brown or wrap_content? Share your style R.style.DialogStyle. and no need to overide onCreateDialog.  You already removed setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, Your Theme).

Comment: I have updated the question with additional information as requested. The app is all Java. Still the situation that, seemingly, the exact same layout and code displays a dialog differently in the live app and the test app on the Galaxy Tab S7. device.

Comment: Remove your onStart functionality 

Set theme  setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);

Comment: Removing the onStart functionality and setting theme to setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen); produces a full screen dialog which is not what is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been resolved by an update by Samsung! I have no idea what the underlying problem was but it no longer is an issue. Thanks to all those who put some thought into it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in `onStart()` method.
Can you try to change like following?

```
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Window win = getDialog().getWindow();
        if (win == null)
            return;

        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        ((Activity) mContext).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = win.getAttributes();
        int contextRect = getContextRect((Activity) mContext);

        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER; //you can change Gravity in here
        params.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT; //you can change width in here
        int screenHeight = contextRect == 0 ? ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT : contextRect;
        params.height = screenHeight;
        win.setAttributes(params);
    }

    private int getContextRect(Activity activity) {
        Rect outRect = new Rect();
        activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(outRect);
        return outRect.height();
    }
```

Comment: Firstly, you did not provide the function getContextRect((Activity) mContext) but I did manage to find this elsewhere. This does not resolve the issue I'm afraid.

Comment: I would like to emphasise that the app has worked and continues to work on most devices and Android versions. There are a number of dialogs in the app and all display correctly except on some of these Samsung Tab S7 devices.

Comment: I edit to add getContextRect() method. But sad to hear it didn't work. Hope you will find solution soon. ^^)

Answer (score 0):

this may help

```
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.FullscreenDialogStyle)
    dialog?.let {
        it.window?.setLayout(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        )
    }
}

    <style name="FullscreenDialogStyle">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
</style>
```